# Write 2d Text on specific point using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
var sourcePos=new THREE.Vector3(-5,0,0);
var targetPos=new THREE.Vector3(-5,2,0);
var direction=new THREE.Vector3().sub(targetPos,sourcePos);
var arrow=newTHREE.ArrowHelper(direction.clone().normalize(),sourcePos,direction.length(),0x00ff00);
scene.add(arrow);
```

At Point sourcePos and targetPos I want give a label Like 'A' and 'B'.
How can I achieve this in three.js?

Comment: A plane with a material map perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Three.js has a `TextGeometry`. When you set the height to 1, it is getting flat like 2d text and you can set it to a specific point in your scene:

```
loader.load( 'helvetiker_bold.typeface.json', function ( font ) {

        var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( content, {

            font: font,
            size: size,
            height: 1 

    });


    textMesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeo, textMaterial );
```

Comment: When height is set to 1, it does not really look flat.